# Author query macro placing query wrongly on the page

Tags: macros, margins

I created a macro to place Query on the margin and the query list on the seperate page at the end of chapter

I have two  problem

- In the two column layout, when text continued from one column to next column
  if query on this para, its clashing to the text, not printing on the margin
  Could you please help me in sorting this out
- I need a dummy page count when query sheet extending to multiple pages
  i.e., chapter 1 ends with page 4 and then two pages of query sheet should be dummy page,
  then chapter 2 should starts on 5th page with out considering the page count of query sheet
  i can able to reduce page count through \addtocounter{page}{-1} for first page query sheet alone,
  i need all query pages should be dummy page count

How to sort of these two issues.

can anyone help me to sort of of these issue

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,twoside,anypage]{book}

\usepackage{showframe,array,ifthen,color}

\definecolor{grayten}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.1}
\makeatletter

\newwrite\query

\long\def \protected@immwrite#1#2#3{%
      \begingroup
       \let\thepage\relax
       #2%
       \let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
       \edef\reserved@a{\immediate\write#1{#3}}%
       \reserved@a
      \endgroup
      \if@nobreak\ifvmode\nobreak\fi\fi}

\AtBeginDocument{\immediate\openout\query \jobname.aqy\relax}

\def\AQ{\@ifnextchar[{\@AQ}{\@AQ[0pt]}}

\newcounter{querycnt}[chapter]

\newdimen\qwidth\qwidth48pt

\def\@AQ[#1]#2{\ifmmode%
              \else%
                \setbox\@tempboxa=\vbox to 0pt{\vspace*{-.8\baselineskip}\vspace*{#1}%
                                         \hbox to \hsize{\refstepcounter{querycnt}%
                                            \if@firstcolumn\hspace*{-\marginparsep}\else\hspace*{1.15\columnwidth}\fi%
                                            \llap{\hbox{\fboxsep1pt\fboxrule0pt
                                            \fcolorbox{red}{grayten}{\color{red}\fontsize{7}{7}\selectfont\reset@font AQ\thequerycnt}}}\hfill}%
                                            \protected@immwrite\query{}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}\protect\@hangfrom{\hbox to \qwidth{\bfseries AQ\thequerycnt\hfill}}#2^^J}
                                      }%
                                    \dp\@tempboxa\z@%
                  \ifvmode%
                      \@tempdima=\prevdepth%
                      \nointerlineskip\box\@tempboxa\nobreak%
                      \prevdepth=\@tempdima%
                  \else%
                      \vadjust{\box\@tempboxa\nobreak}%
                  \fi%
             \fi%
            }
\def\querytitle{\ifnum\c@querycnt>0\noindent {\Huge{\bf Chapter-\thechapter}: Queries\endgraf}\vspace*{36pt}
\noindent\hrulefill\endgraf%
\fi
}

\def\showquery{\clearpage
                \onecolumn\thispagestyle{empty}
                \addtocounter{page}{-1}
                \immediate\closeout\query
                \querytitle
                \makeatletter
                    \input{\jobname.aqy}
                \makeatother
                \twocolumn
                \immediate\openout\query=\jobname.aqy
               }

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\chapter{Physical design and integration of the software}

The standard symbols in process\AQ{Author query1} mapping consist of several shapes with\AQ{Author query} specific use. An oval shape shows the input to start the process or the output at the end of the process.\AQ{Author query} An arrow shows the direction of the process flow or step. A box or rectangle\AQ{Author query} shows a task or activity\AQ{Author query} being performed or executed.\AQ{Author query} A diamond shape is a decision point whereby a question\AQ{Author query} is asked that is\AQ{Author query} answerable by either yes or no.\AQ{Author query} There is only one arrow out of each activity box. If more than one arrow is needed,\AQ{Author query} then it could be that a decision diamond needs\AQ{Author query} to be asked. Other shapes represent a document or report, data or a subprocess (see ).

As introduced in the {Chapter 5}, flowcharts or maps play an\AQ{Author query} important function\AQ{Author query} in the assessment phase. As a tool, flowchart defines and provides\AQ{Author query} visibility to the process by analyzing processes and/or\AQ{Author query} clarifying a situation to improve knowledge and understanding\AQ{Author query} of the organization.\AQ{Author query} Through the use of steps and workflow sequences, relationships between\AQ{Author query} steps are established in a picture representation or process map. The sequence of steps in a process, with different types of actions is displayed by boxes and other\AQ{Author query} standard symbols facilitate the analysis of a solution to a given problem. This can be completed with Microsoft Visio or even in a word document if Visio is unavailable.

Scheduling current state and future\AQ{Author query} state process sessions for the project team to participate\AQ{Author query} through discussion and specifying each step in order will help clarify\AQ{Author query} the gaps and design.\AQ{Author query} The deliverable outcome of these process sessions are the flowcharts that provide\AQ{Author query} knowledge on the process as a whole. This helps\AQ{Author query} to bring common understanding and an awareness that users working in one part of the process must work collaboratively with those in other parts of the process so that the whole process can flow smoothly.\AQ{Author query}

Reaching an\AQ{Author query} understanding of the work process\AQ{Author query} is part of the workflow analysis normally conducted before automating any process,\AQ{Author query} information, and application of the organization.\AQ{Author query} Focus groups or work groups may also be helpful for more in-depth\AQ{Author query} exploration of topics that arise\AQ{Author query} to better understand workflow and any potential barriers. These workgroup meetings can also discuss optimizing processes, review impacted policies, and procedures.

This analysis\AQ{Author query} is focused on the physical design\AQ{Author query} and integration\AQ{Author query} of the software, which involves an illustration\AQ{Author query} of how the application\AQ{Author query} will function or work within\AQ{Author query} the technical environment. The focus of the NIS\AQ{Author query} in regards to technical\AQ{Author query} requirements\AQ{Author query} is to ask questions, raise considerations, and understand where the technical requirements impact the workflow. Identifying the system technical requirements may include hardware assessments, software features and functionality, database and reporting, as well as integration requirements. Hardware equipment\AQ{Author query} needs may include desktop computers with keyboards, availability of electric outlets and cables for the additional computers,\AQ{Author query} mobile workstations with computers, and connected printers for every inpatient unit, pharmacy, laboratory, radiology, and other clinical or patient care areas that would be affected. The repository and servers where the data will be held need to be taken into account before the implementation.\AQ{Author query}

Scheduling current state and future state process sessions for the project team to participate through discussion and specifying each step in order will help clarify the gaps and design. The deliverable outcome of these process sessions are the flowcharts that provide knowledge on the process as a whole. This helps to bring common understanding and an awareness that users working in one part of the process must work collaboratively with those in other parts of the process so that the whole process can flow smoothly.\AQ{Author query}

Reaching an understanding of the work process is part of the workflow\AQ{Author query} analysis normally conducted before automating any process, information, and application of the organization. Focus groups or work groups may also be helpful for more in-depth exploration of topics that arise to better understand workflow and any potential barriers. These workgroup meetings can also discuss optimizing processes, review impacted policies, and procedures.

This analysis is focused on the physical design and integration of the software, which involves an illustration of how the application will function or work within the technical environment. The focus of the NIS in regards to technical requirements is to ask questions, raise considerations, and understand where the technical requirements impact the workflow. Identifying the system technical\AQ{Author query} requirements may include hardware assessments, software features and functionality, database and reporting, as well as integration requirements. Hardware equipment needs may include desktop computers with keyboards, availability of electric outlets and cables for the additional computers, mobile workstations with computers, and connected printers for every inpatient unit, pharmacy, laboratory, radiology, and\AQ{Author query} other clinical\AQ{Author query} or patient care areas that would be affected. The repository and servers where the data will be held need to be taken into account before the implementation.\AQ{Author query}

The infrastructure needs to be in place and invested in before the start of the project. The technical planning needs to include system maintenance once the application is operational, provision of ongoing help desk support, as well as, disaster recovery plan. Confidentiality and security of the system are important points that must be reviewed ensuring that the system is Health Insurance Portability and Accountability Act (HIPAA) compliant. It is essential to include subject matter experts such as the IT security, network, and desktop teams in the assessment phase. Technical questions have to be verified with the vendor particularly on what the system can do being that systems are deep with many layers. The technical components are the responsibility of the technical analyst that is part of the project team wherein he or she provides guidance in this process. Continuing with the same example for the blood transfusion verification project, {Table 6.6} lists examples of technical, security, and system support requirements.


Reaching an understanding of the work process\AQ{Author query} is part of the workflow analysis normally conducted before automating any process, information, and application of the organization.\AQ{Author query} Focus groups or work groups may also be helpful for more in-depth exploration of topics that arise to better understand workflow and any potential barriers. These workgroup meetings can also discuss optimizing processes, review impacted policies, and procedures.

This analysis is focused on the physical design and\AQ{Author query} integration of the software, which involves an illustration of how the application will function or work within the technical environment. The focus of the NIS in regards to technical requirements is to ask questions, raise considerations, and understand where the technical requirements impact the workflow. Identifying the system technical requirements may include hardware assessments, software features and functionality, database and reporting, as well as integration requirements. Hardware equipment needs may include desktop computers with keyboards, availability of electric outlets and cables for the additional computers, mobile workstations with computers, and connected printers for every inpatient unit, pharmacy, laboratory, radiology, and other clinical or patient care areas that would be affected. The repository and servers where the data will be held need to be taken into account before the implementation.

The infrastructure needs to be in place and invested in before\AQ{Author query} the start of the project. The technical planning needs to include system maintenance once the application is operational, provision of ongoing help desk support, as well as, disaster recovery plan. Confidentiality and security of the system are important points that must be reviewed ensuring that the system is Health Insurance Portability and Accountability Act (HIPAA) compliant. It is essential to include subject matter experts such as the IT security, network, and desktop teams in the assessment phase. Technical questions have to be verified with the vendor particularly on what the system can do being that systems are deep with many layers. The technical components are the responsibility of the technical analyst that is part of the project team wherein he or she provides guidance in this process. Continuing with the same example for the blood transfusion verification project, {Table 6.6} lists examples of technical, security, and system support requirements.


Reaching an understanding of the work process is part of the\AQ{Author query} workflow analysis normally conducted before automating any process, information, and application of the organization. Focus groups or work groups may also be helpful for more in-depth exploration of topics that arise to better understand workflow and any potential barriers. These workgroup meetings can also discuss optimizing processes, review impacted policies, and procedures.

This analysis is focused on the physical design and integration\AQ{Author query} of the software, which involves an illustration of how the application will function or work within the technical environment. The focus of the NIS in regards to technical requirements is to ask questions, raise considerations, and understand where the technical requirements impact the workflow. Identifying the system technical requirements may include hardware assessments, software features and functionality, database and reporting, as well as integration requirements. Hardware equipment needs may include desktop computers with keyboards, availability of electric outlets and cables for the additional computers, mobile workstations with computers, and connected printers for every inpatient unit, pharmacy, laboratory, radiology, and other clinical or patient care areas that would be affected. The repository and servers where the data will be held need to be taken into account before the implementation.

The infrastructure needs to be in place and invested in before the start of the project. The technical planning needs to include system maintenance once the application is operational, provision of ongoing help desk support, as well as, disaster recovery plan. Confidentiality and security of the system are important points that must be reviewed ensuring that the system is Health Insurance Portability and Accountability Act (HIPAA) compliant. It is essential to include subject matter experts such as the IT security, network, and desktop teams in the assessment phase. Technical questions have to be verified with the vendor particularly on what the system can do being that systems are deep with many layers. The technical components are the responsibility of the technical analyst that is part of the project team wherein he or she provides guidance in this process. Continuing with the same example for the blood transfusion verification project, {Table 6.6} lists examples of technical, security, and system support requirements.

Reaching an understanding of the work process is part of the workflow analysis normally conducted before automating any process, information, and application of the organization. Focus groups or work groups may also be helpful for more in-depth exploration of topics that arise to better understand workflow and any potential barriers. These workgroup meetings can also discuss optimizing processes, review impacted policies, and procedures.

This analysis is focused on the physical design and integration of the software, which involves an illustration of how the application will function or work within the technical environment. The focus of the NIS in regards to technical requirements is to ask questions, raise considerations, and understand where the technical requirements impact the workflow. Identifying the system technical requirements may include hardware assessments, software features and functionality, database and reporting, as well as integration requirements. Hardware equipment needs may include desktop computers with keyboards, availability of electric outlets and cables for the additional computers, mobile workstations with computers, and connected printers for every inpatient unit, pharmacy, laboratory, radiology, and other clinical or patient care areas that would be affected. The repository and servers where the data will be held need to be taken into account before the implementation.

The infrastructure needs to be in place and invested in before the start of the project.

\showquery


\chapter{Second chapter}

This analysis is focused on the physical design and integration of the software, which involves an illustration of how the application will function or work within the technical environment. The focus of the NIS in regards to technical requirements is to ask questions, raise considerations, and understand where the technical requirements impact the workflow. Identifying the system technical requirements may include hardware assessments, software features and functionality, database and reporting, as well as integration requirements. Hardware equipment needs may include desktop computers with keyboards, availability of electric outlets and cables for the additional computers, mobile workstations with computers, and connected printers for every inpatient unit, pharmacy, laboratory, radiology, and other clinical or patient care areas that would be affected. The repository and servers where the data will be held need to be taken into account before the implementation

\showquery

\end{document}
```